# Position div on expand to the top

Tags: jquery, css

I have a few jquery portlets, I want to expand them to view more information.

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/montel388/kdp0f9vs/7/)

But the problem is that expanded window stay at the same position. The code I used for it:

```
.portlet-fullscreen {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 80%;
}
```

Also is there any way to position it to the left?

Comment: so you want your portal to shrink if click on - and expand if click on plus,right?

Comment: give your portlet-fullscreen class a `left:0` or `left:10%`

Comment: Nice coincidence @d-h-e even i was answering the same :)

Comment: @Leothelion yes thats correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help you by giving left: 0

```
.portlet-fullscreen {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 80%;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried it, but the problem is that i have menu on left side of the window and it moves right inside of it, is there a way to keep it inside div

Comment: I did  not get it can you put it in the fiddle if possible

Comment: I think you can give left: Xpx or X% as per the width of the side menu so that portlet-fullscreen will be inside the div after the side menu view @YevgeniyBagackiy